# How can I process SVG images to be the same height

Tags: c#, string, svg

##### Background information:

I have code where a string is converted into an SVG image the size of an A4 paper.

The letters have specific sizes:

- lowercase-normal letters (example: abc):

  - width: 5mm
  - height: 10mm

**[Example Image "a"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m9vwqzq84olOnseci8wf8dEaVNGyzhCW/view?usp=share_link)**

- lowercase-deep letters that go under the line (eg: fjg):

  - width: 5mm
  - height: 15mm

**[Example Image "j"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fHMixjPCmOraDo17Z4z8W76jWX1DucZG/view?usp=share_link)**

- uppercase letters (example: ABC):

  - partially go under the line
  - width: 5mm
  - height: 10mm

**[Example Image "A"](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EQhaz47KfNi4YdCVeXBH_UXLmbVlpBLj/view?usp=share_link)**

##### The problem:

- Lowercase-normal letters are rendered correctly
- Capital and lowercase-deep letters are rendered incorrectly:

  - See [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yti0A.png)
  - I need it to be on the same upper line

I've tried asking `chatGPT` but the answers did not provide the solution I needed

Here is the code:
I edited the code to fit this question

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var svgDocs = new List<XDocument>();
        string InputText = @"";
        string letterwith = "5mm";
        string letterheight = "10mm";
        string wideletterwith = "32mm";
        string wideletterheight = "40mm";
        string deepletterheight = "15mm";
        string a4width = "210mm";
        string a4height = "297mm";
        int yOffset = 65;

        Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie Ihren Wunschtext ein:");
        InputText = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < InputText.Length; i++)
        {
            char letter = InputText[i];
            switch (letter)
            {
                case ' ':
                    var svgSpace = GenerateNewSVG(@"Images\Letters\Capital\Space\");
                    svgDocs.Add(svgSpace);
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    string folderPathA = @"Images\Letters\Capital\A\";
                    string[] filesA = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathA, "*.svg");
                    if (filesA.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileA = filesA[random.Next(filesA.Length)];
                        var svgA = XDocument.Load(randomFileA);
                        svgA.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgA.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgA);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'a':
                    string folderPatha = @"Images\Letters\Normal\a\";
                    string[] filesa = Directory.GetFiles(folderPatha, "*.svg");
                    if (filesa.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFilea = filesa[random.Next(filesa.Length)];
                        var svga = XDocument.Load(randomFilea);
                        svga.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svga.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svga);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    string folderPathB = @"Images\Letters\Capital\B\";
                    string[] filesB = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathB, "*.svg");
                    if (filesB.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileB = filesB[random.Next(filesB.Length)];
                        var svgB = XDocument.Load(randomFileB);
                        svgB.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgB.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgB);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    string folderPathb = @"Images\Letters\Normal\b\";
                    string[] filesb = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathb, "*.svg");
                    if (filesb.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileb = filesb[random.Next(filesb.Length)];
                        var svgb = XDocument.Load(randomFileb);
                        svgb.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgb.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgb);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    string folderPathC = @"Images\Letters\Capital\C\";
                    string[] filesC = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathC, "*.svg");
                    if (filesC.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileC = filesC[random.Next(filesC.Length)];
                        var svgC = XDocument.Load(randomFileC);
                        svgC.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgC.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgC);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    string folderPathc = @"Images\Letters\Normal\c\";
                    string[] filesc = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathc, "*.svg");
                    if (filesc.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFilec = filesc[random.Next(filesc.Length)];
                        var svgc = XDocument.Load(randomFilec);
                        svgc.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgc.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgc);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    string folderPathD = @"Images\Letters\Capital\D\";
                    string[] filesD = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathD, "*.svg");
                    if (filesD.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileD = filesD[random.Next(filesD.Length)];
                        var svgD = XDocument.Load(randomFileD);
                        svgD.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgD.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgD);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    string folderPathd = @"Images\Letters\Normal\d\";
                    string[] filesd = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathd, "*.svg");
                    if (filesd.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFiled = filesd[random.Next(filesd.Length)];
                        var svgd = XDocument.Load(randomFiled);
                        svgd.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgd.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgd);
                    }
                    break;
                
                case 'I':
                    string folderPathI = @"Images\Letters\Capital\I\";
                    string[] filesI = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathI, "*.svg");
                    if (filesI.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileI = filesI[random.Next(filesI.Length)];
                        var svgI = XDocument.Load(randomFileI);
                        svgI.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgI.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgI);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    string folderPathi = @"Images\Letters\Normal\i\";
                    string[] filesi = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathi, "*.svg");
                    if (filesi.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFilei = filesi[random.Next(filesi.Length)];
                        var svgi = XDocument.Load(randomFilei);
                        svgi.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgi.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgi);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'J':
                    string folderPathJ = @"Images\Letters\Capital\J\";
                    string[] filesJ = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathJ, "*.svg");
                    if (filesJ.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileJ = filesJ[random.Next(filesJ.Length)];
                        var svgJ = XDocument.Load(randomFileJ);
                        svgJ.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgJ.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgJ);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'j':
                    string folderPathj = @"Images\Letters\Normal\j\";
                    string[] filesj = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathj, "*.svg");
                    if (filesj.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFilej = filesj[random.Next(filesj.Length)];
                        var svgj = XDocument.Load(randomFilej);
                        svgj.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgj.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", deepletterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgj);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'K':
                    string folderPathK = @"Images\Letters\Capital\K\";
                    string[] filesK = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathK, "*.svg");
                    if (filesK.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileK = filesK[random.Next(filesK.Length)];
                        var svgK = XDocument.Load(randomFileK);
                        svgK.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgK.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgK);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'k':
                    string folderPathk = @"Images\Letters\Normal\k\";
                    string[] filesk = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathk, "*.svg");
                    if (filesk.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFilek = filesk[random.Next(filesk.Length)];
                        var svgk = XDocument.Load(randomFilek);
                        svgk.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgk.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgk);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'L':
                    string folderPathL = @"Images\Letters\Capital\L\";
                    string[] filesL = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathL, "*.svg");
                    if (filesL.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileL = filesL[random.Next(filesL.Length)];
                        var svgL = XDocument.Load(randomFileL);
                        svgL.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgL.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgL);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    string folderPathl = @"Images\Letters\Normal\l\";
                    string[] filesl = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathl, "*.svg");
                    if (filesl.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFilel = filesl[random.Next(filesl.Length)];
                        var svgl = XDocument.Load(randomFilel);
                        svgl.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgl.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgl);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'M':
                    string folderPathM = @"Images\Letters\Capital\M\";
                    string[] filesM = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathM, "*.svg");
                    if (filesM.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileM = filesM[random.Next(filesM.Length)];
                        var svgM = XDocument.Load(randomFileM);
                        svgM.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", wideletterwith);
                        svgM.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", wideletterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgM);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'm':
                    string folderPathm = @"Images\Letters\Normal\m\";
                    string[] filesm = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathm, "*.svg");
                    if (filesm.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFilem = filesm[random.Next(filesm.Length)];
                        var svgm = XDocument.Load(randomFilem);
                        svgm.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgm.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgm);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'N':
                    string folderPathN = @"Images\Letters\Capital\N\";
                    string[] filesN = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathN, "*.svg");
                    if (filesN.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileN = filesN[random.Next(filesN.Length)];
                        var svgN = XDocument.Load(randomFileN);
                        svgN.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", wideletterwith);
                        svgN.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", wideletterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgN);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    string folderPathn = @"Images\Letters\Normal\n\";
                    string[] filesn = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathn, "*.svg");
                    if (filesn.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFilen = filesn[random.Next(filesn.Length)];
                        var svgn = XDocument.Load(randomFilen);
                        svgn.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgn.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgn);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'O':
                    string folderPathO = @"Images\Letters\Capital\O\";
                    string[] filesO = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathO, "*.svg");
                    if (filesO.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileO = filesO[random.Next(filesO.Length)];
                        var svgO = XDocument.Load(randomFileO);
                        svgO.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgO.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgO);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    string folderPatho = @"Images\Letters\Normal\o\";
                    string[] fileso = Directory.GetFiles(folderPatho, "*.svg");
                    if (fileso.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileo = fileso[random.Next(fileso.Length)];
                        var svgo = XDocument.Load(randomFileo);
                        svgo.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgo.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgo);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'P':
                    string folderPathP = @"Images\Letters\Capital\P\";
                    string[] filesP = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathP, "*.svg");
                    if (filesP.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileP = filesP[random.Next(filesP.Length)];
                        var svgP = XDocument.Load(randomFileP);
                        svgP.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgP.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgP);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    string folderPathp = @"Images\Letters\Normal\p\";
                    string[] filesp = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathp, "*.svg");
                    if (filesp.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFilep = filesp[random.Next(filesp.Length)];
                        var svgp = XDocument.Load(randomFilep);
                        svgp.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgp.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", deepletterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgp);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                    string folderPathQ = @"Images\Letters\Capital\Q\";
                    string[] filesQ = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathQ, "*.svg");
                    if (filesQ.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileQ = filesQ[random.Next(filesQ.Length)];
                        var svgQ = XDocument.Load(randomFileQ);
                        svgQ.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgQ.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgQ);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'q':
                    string folderPathq = @"Images\Letters\Normal\q\";
                    string[] filesq = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathq, "*.svg");
                    if (filesq.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileq = filesq[random.Next(filesq.Length)];
                        var svgq = XDocument.Load(randomFileq);
                        svgq.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgq.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", deepletterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgq);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'R':
                    string folderPathR = @"Images\Letters\Capital\R\";
                    string[] filesR = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathR, "*.svg");
                    if (filesR.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileR = filesR[random.Next(filesR.Length)];
                        var svgR = XDocument.Load(randomFileR);
                        svgR.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgR.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgR);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    string folderPathr = @"Images\Letters\Normal\r\";
                    string[] filesr = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathr, "*.svg");
                    if (filesr.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFiler = filesr[random.Next(filesr.Length)];
                        var svgr = XDocument.Load(randomFiler);
                        svgr.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgr.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgr);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    string folderPathS = @"Images\Letters\Capital\S\";
                    string[] filesS = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathS, "*.svg");
                    if (filesS.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileS = filesS[random.Next(filesS.Length)];
                        var svgS = XDocument.Load(randomFileS);
                        svgS.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgS.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgS);
                    }
                    break;
                case 's':
                    string folderPaths = @"Images\Letters\Normal\s\";
                    string[] filess = Directory.GetFiles(folderPaths, "*.svg");
                    if (filess.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFiles = filess[random.Next(filess.Length)];
                        var svgs = XDocument.Load(randomFiles);
                        svgs.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgs.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgs);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'T':
                    string folderPathT = @"Images\Letters\Capital\T\";
                    string[] filesT = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathT, "*.svg");
                    if (filesT.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileT = filesT[random.Next(filesT.Length)];
                        var svgT = XDocument.Load(randomFileT);
                        svgT.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgT.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgT);
                    }
                    break;
                case 't':
                    string folderPatht = @"Images\Letters\Normal\t\";
                    string[] filest = Directory.GetFiles(folderPatht, "*.svg");
                    if (filest.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFilet = filest[random.Next(filest.Length)];
                        var svgt = XDocument.Load(randomFilet);
                        svgt.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgt.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgt);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'U':
                    string folderPathU = @"Images\Letters\Capital\U\";
                    string[] filesU = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathU, "*.svg");
                    if (filesU.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileU = filesU[random.Next(filesU.Length)];
                        var svgU = XDocument.Load(randomFileU);
                        svgU.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgU.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgU);
                    }
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    string folderPathu = @"Images\Letters\Normal\u\";
                    string[] filesu = Directory.GetFiles(folderPathu, "*.svg");
                    if (filesu.Length > 0)
                    {
                        string randomFileu = filesu[random.Next(filesu.Length)];
                        var svgu = XDocument.Load(randomFileu);
                        svgu.Root.SetAttributeValue("width", letterwith);
                        svgu.Root.SetAttributeValue("height", letterheight);
                        svgDocs.Add(svgu);
                    }
                    break;


            }
        }



        XDocument combinedSvg = new XDocument(
            new XElement("svg",
                new XAttribute("width", a4width),
                new XAttribute("height", a4height)));

        int xOffset = 0;
        foreach (var svg in svgDocs)
        {
            svg.Root.SetAttributeValue("x", xOffset.ToString());
            combinedSvg.Root.Add(svg.Root);

            xOffset += int.Parse(svg.Root.Attribute("width").Value.Substring(0, svg.Root.Attribute("width").Value.Length - 2)) - 16;
        }


        combinedSvg.Save("combined.svg");
    }
    private static XDocument GenerateNewSVG(string folderPath)
    {
        string letterwith = "5mm";
        string letterheight = "10mm";
        XNamespace svg = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
        XDocument svgDoc = new XDocument(
            new XElement(svg + "svg",
                new XAttribute("version", "1.1"),
                new XAttribute("width", letterwith),
                new XAttribute("height", letterheight),
                new XElement(svg + "rect",
                    new XAttribute("x", "0"),
                    new XAttribute("y", "0"),
                    new XAttribute("width", letterwith),
                    new XAttribute("height", letterheight),
                    new XAttribute("fill", "white"))
            )
        );

        return svgDoc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the problematic letter images